# Must collisions be detected "before" or "after" moving the object?

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I want to ask this question the most theoretically I can. Forget about programming languages and APIs, please.

Let's suppose that we have a square that we move with the keyboard. In the screen where our  square lives, there exists an obstacle too. This obstacle is a rectangle, and it is solid. This means that if, for example, our square hits it from the left side (the left side of the obstacle), the square won't be able to advance in that direction (like a wall).

This is very simple, so now, I think there are two main ways to approach this problem. Let's suppose that we use hit-testing collision for detecting it:

-Make the move (with time-difference between frames), and see if the new move made a collision. If the new move made a collision, "correct" the coordinate that made the hit (it could be x or y).

-See if updating x will make a collision. If it makes it, don't update x (or update it at it's maximum before collisioning the obstacle). Make the same with y.

Actually, I'm using the second method, and it works perfectly! First, I tried the first method, but I saw a big problem with it. When you make a collision after moving, it means that my player got "into" the obstacle. But the collision could have been caused from a lot of possible directions, so how will I know which one is the correct direction in which I have to correct the coordinates? It may be done well, but it's complicating the code when I can simply choose the second way.

I'm doing this in SDL, and the second way works nicely.

What's your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

It really does depend on how complicated you want your collisions to be.  If you have something that works for you, then use it by all means!  At any rate, the important part is to resolve collisions before rendering.  ;)

But really, projecting a path to check for potential collisions is not significantly different from moving objects first and then moving them back as needed.  It's just a difference of how you look at it and how your algorithms work.  Checking for potential collisions (checking before moving) means making something like a swept body shape and checking that against other sweeps for overlap, then moving the objects to the extrapolated final position.  Checking for past collisions (checking after moving) is just checking overlap of the objects themselves (and avoiding high speed tunneling).

If you need to resolve collisions between many objects, then (in my opinion) you should move everything before checking overlap.  You must retain the old positions and velocities so you can slide the objects back until they no longer overlap and then give them proper momenta accordingly.  You might still want to perform substeps to bring the objects to their final positions.

Overall, these problems have been solved by some very good libraries.  If you need good physical collisions, try one of them out before you go wild with making your own.

Answer (score 0):

your way works fine for square obstacles, but for curved obstacles if you want to bounce off them you need to calculate the angle of the sirface where the collision happened.
take snooker games for example.

If collisions are rare it may make sense to move first and check for collisions and if there is a collision undo the move and then look for details of the cause of the collision.